# AWS Lambda To DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to connect my front-end, via a lambda function, to DynamoDB. I cannot understand how to fix the lambda function for it to work. Currently it is just posting undefined to PK and SK.

**Lambda Function**

```
"use strict";
require("dotenv").config();
// const config = require("../../config/keys");
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
AWS.config.update({ region: "eu-west-1" });
const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const addJobListing = async (data) => {
  const body = {
    TableName: "XXXXXX",
    Item: {
      "PK": `${data.acc}${data.jobId}${data.startDate}`,
      "SK": `${data.jobId}.${data.startDate}`,
      "Days Off": data.daysOff,
      "Start Date": data.startDate,
      "Job ID": data.jobId,
      "Contract Length": data.contractLength,
      "Expiration Date": data.expirationDate,
      Created: {
        M: {
          CREATED: {
            M: { date: data.createdDate, time: data.createdTime },
          },
        },
      },
      Insurance: data.insurance,
      Title: data.title,
      Holidays: data.holidays,
      Ages: data.ages,
      "Flight Reimbursement": data.flightReimbursement,
      Curriculum: data.curriculum,
      "Account ID": data.accountId,
      "Minimum Monthly Salary Before Tax": data.minimumMonthlySalaryBeforeTax,
      "Housing Allowance": data.housingAllowance,
      Responsibilities: data.responsibilities,
      "Job Closest Metro": data.jobClosestMetro,
      "Job Requirements": data.jobRequirements,
      "Job Type": data.jobType,
      "Z-VISA Reimbursement": data.zVisaReimbursement,
      Meals: data.meals,
      Subject: data.subject,
      "Salary Information": data.salaryInformation,
      "Maximum Monthly Salary Before Tax": data.maximumMonthlySalaryBeforeTax,
      "Vacancy Status": data.vacancyStatus,
      "Contract Completion Bonus": data.contractCompletionBonus,
      "Last Modified": {
        M: {
          LAST_MODIFIED: {
            M: {
              date: data.modifiedDate,
              time: data.modifiedTime,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };

  console.log("Job Listing ID", `${data.jobId}.${data.startDate}`);
  return await documentClient.put(body).promise();
};

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log("PRINT STRING", event);
  const response = await addJobListing(JSON.parse(event.body));
  console.log("resp", response);
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", // Required for CORS support to work
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true, // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(response),
  };
};
```

On **CloudWatch**, the errors are:
`resp undefined`, `Job Listing ID undefined.undefined`.

```
 body: '{\r\n' +
    '    "Item": {\r\n' +
    '    "PK": "ACC#010117/01/2022",\r\n' +
    '    "SK": "01.17/01/2022",\r\n' +
    '    "Start Date": "17/01/2022",\r\n' +
    '    "Job ID": "01"\r\n' +
    '    }\r\n' +
    '  }',
```

The data I am sending to the endpoint API via API Gateway is this JSON:

```
{
    "Item": {
    "PK": "ACC#010117/01/2022",
    "SK": "01.17/01/2022",
    "Start Date": "17/01/2022",
    "Job ID": "01"
    }
  }
```

**Postman Information Returned**

```
Request Headers:
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: xxxxxxxxx
Host: xxxxxxxxxxx-execute.aws.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 130

Request Body:
Response Headers
Date: Mon, 17 Jan 2022 18:39:41 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-credentials: true
Apigw-Requestid: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Response Body:
0
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the JSON of your request body:

```
{\r\n' +
    '    "Item": {\r\n' +
    '    "PK": "ACC#010117/01/2022",\r\n' +
    '    "SK": "01.17/01/2022",\r\n' +
    '    "Start Date": "17/01/2022",\r\n' +
    '    "Job ID": "01"\r\n' +
    '    }\r\n' +
    '  }
```

There is no key `acc`, or `jobId` or `startDate` or really any of the keys you are trying to use. The key names have capital letters and spaces in them. And `acc` is definitely not a key at all.

So for example this:

```
   "PK": `${data.acc}${data.jobId}${data.startDate}`,
```

Needs to be this:

```
   "PK": data['PK'],
```

And this:

```
   "Job ID": data.jobId,
```

Needs to be this:

```
   "Job ID": data['Job ID'],
```

Comment: Hi Mark, I had to add data["Item"]["Job ID"] for it to work. 

Would you have any idea how to make it work for Mapped or SS attributes as well as strings?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "mapped or SS attributes".

Comment: Hi Mark, AWS defines attributes. You can find more information here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html

Comment: Those are attribute types, and they are DynamoDB attributes that you need to build from the String that were submitted to your API Gateway and passed into your function.

Comment: Last question:

For adding a Created column in the table, I am trying to recreate this with JSON: { "CREATED" : { "M" : { "date" : { "S" : "12/01/2022" }, "time" : { "S" : "09:02:12:00" } } } } 

How would you advise writing the JSON to reproduce this in the DynamoDB Table?